Router OS шлет с адрессов не поподающие под маску
Имеется два CHR router OS маршрутизатора находящихся в разных местах поддерживающие связь по wireguard. И мне в больную голову стукнула идея сделать на маршрутизаторе A две сети в рамках одного туннеля где сеть 10.0.0.0/24 отвечает за домашнюю сеть и где 10.1.0.0/24 отвечала бы за сеть выходящуюю в другую страну дальше по VPN. Соответственно А и B маршрутизаторы имеют по 2 адреса, на маршрутизаторе A определением что клиент хочет попасть в VPN сеть осуществляется собственно правило Mangle который перекидывает подключения из main таблицы в VPN ну и на B стороне свои правила для трафика который я хочу гонять по VPN (mangle prerouting action rote to 10.1.0.1)
собственно для чего я все это объясняю, все это работает на стороне В до тех пор пока роутер не перезагрузится, и чтобы все вернуть нужно адрес 10.0.0.1 перевключить и то не всегда это работает. он банально начинает транслировать с адреса 10.0.0.2 на адрес A маршрутизатора 10.0.0.1 (естественно вместо должных и указанных адрессов 10.1.0.2 и 10.1.0.1)
прошло года два как я не понимаю как это работает и почему, хочется узнать почему так происходит ну и послушать предложения как сделать это другим образом (только не надо писать что можно подключиться к своему конечному хосту VPN напрямую)
